react and springboot packaged war deployment on tomcat
I have react frontend and springboot backend. I want to bundle both into a single war file and deploy it on tomcat server (internal/external both works)
This is my folder structure:

and these are the tasks i used in build.gradle file:
Reference article - https://medium.com/@sanketpatilcs/spring-boot-application-with-packaged-react-js-app-with-gradle-build-76a2c15e0280
node {
    download=false
    workDir = file("${project.projectDir}/frontend/nodejs")
    npmWorkDir = file("${project.projectDir}/frontend/npm")
    nodeModulesDir = file("${project.projectDir}/frontend")
}

task appNpmInstall(type: NpmTask){
    description = " read packge.json and install all jars"
    workingDir = file("${project.projectDir}/frontend")
    args =["install"]
}

task appNpmBuild(type: NpmTask){
    description = "Builds applciation for your frontend "
    workingDir = file("${project.projectDir}/frontend")
    args =["run", "build"]
}

task copyToFrontend(type: Copy){
    from "$projectDir/frontend/build"
    into "$buildDir/resources/main/static"
}

appNpmBuild.dependsOn appNpmInstall
copyToFrontend.dependsOn appNpmBuild
compileJava.dependsOn copyToFrontend

Now i have a war package in build -> libs and I've verified that static folder exists inside WEB-INF -> classes inside the war file

Now, I've tried to deploy the war file both internally using "java -jar build/libs/automation.war" and externally using tomcat.
But when i go to localhost:8080 or even localhost:8080/index.html -> i get Whitelabel error page

In the logs I get :
2024-11-11 15:55:00.072  WARN 11844 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "index.html"]

Has anyone encountered such error or has possible solution for it? I can provide more information as required. Thank you

A static directory in static doesn't seem right. Also your copyToFrontend seems wrong, why the additional path? And the sources should be in src/main/resources not sure what resources/main is.

@M.Deinum I've tried putting index.html out of outer static folder too. And checked the relative path of css and js files in index.html (it is correct).
when creating jar/war, springboot first copies content from src/main/resources to build/resources/main, so I tried pasting directly into build folder (I've tried copying into src/main/resources too)
